# How to create 4 dymanic pages using database values

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, oop, get

I currently have 4 pages(about, interviews, ask a q, contact) per people and I have 250+ people and it takes a long time to create a new people to the site

What is the best way to have just 4 pages(about, interview, ask a q, contact) that loops through the database people and creates their pages on the fly when the user requests them?

here's an example of a person on the site http://starsQA.com/aaron-cole

I'm thinking of using $_GET variables from the database and changing the url using .htaccess rewriting, but I have no clue how to do this or if it's even possible

the site uses html, php, mysql and oop

What is the best way to achieve this?

I have added this:

```
<?php session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
include("db_conn.php");
$qry_string = "select * from stars INNER JOIN roles ON roles.starID = stars.starID where stars.starID = ?";
$prep = $pdo_conn->prepare($qry_string);  
$prep->execute(array($_GET['id']));
$result = $prep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$pieces = explode(" ", $result['starName']);
$gender = "him"; 
?>
```

and now if you use http://www.starsqa.com/about?id=52 you can aaron cole and id=6 lindsey mckeon

How to figure out how to change the url to http://www.starsqa.com/about?id=52 to http://starsQA.com/aaron-cole-about

tried this, but i didn't seem to work: 
sending a user from starsQA.com/aaron-cole-about to starsQA.com/about?id=52) :

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
 RewriteRule ^/aaron-cole-about$ /about?id=52 [L]
```

here's my current .htaccess file

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/aaron-cole-about$ /about?id=52 [L]
```

Is it possible that the user entered in aaron-cole-about and behind the scenes it uses about?id=52 but still shows the user aaron-cole-about ???

Comment: oops fixed the link now try it

Comment: What are you doing currently? Is there a script adding someone in the base and generating HTML files, and that script is slow? Or are you creating them manually?

Comment: creating them manually

Comment: i'm looking to generate php files, i have never used scripts before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it cannot be termed a strict duplicate, does this answer help you get an idea.

[how do i create a unique php page for each row in a mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175588/how-do-i-create-a-unique-php-page-for-each-row-in-a-mysql-database)

Both answers together would allow you to create all the pages.  Though you need four pages per record, it should not be very different to loop through them.

then rules similar to the one below

RewriteRule ^about/([^/]+)_([^?/]+).html /about.php?personid=$2

The first part ^about says anything with url http://yoursite.com/about/ should use this rule.  In an url like http://yoursite.com/about/xxxx_1234.html the first part ([^/]+) and ([^?/]+) indicate that the it would split the actual url into xxxx 1234 and html then the rule would redirect the user to about to about.php?personid=1234

A combination of these two should do for you.  Hope this helps

Comment: the link above looks helpful checking it out now thanks, i thought it would be easy to do, guess i'm overthinking it and getting all confused in the process

Comment: It is easy to do, or I would say its something done over and over again, but on another note, why dont you just use wordpress (or another CMS), that would make it a lot easier

Comment: i couldn't find a cms that uses php and oop methods and allows me to use all of the things i want to create. so far i have http://www.starsqa.com/aaron-cole-about?id=52 (doesn't seem to be working haha)

Comment: Somehow the url is still broken for me but its not hard, please try the above fully

Comment: i have i think, it's abit confusing, to be honest

Comment: edited question above, made some process

Comment: for that structured URL to work, you somehow need an ID to be part of the URL or some value that can be uniquely passed on to the PHP that serves the page (like the 1234 in my example)

Comment: so it's not possible that url can say as aaron-cole-about but behind the scenes uses about?id=52 but no-ones says that one?

Comment: kinda like they can use either url to see the page

Comment: The only condition is it should be unique, if you want to make it like  name to the user and id to the database, then you have to manually redirect each page, which is not difficult but time consuming especially to maintain